# why is checkbox button not show first?

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<div id="showTask">
<label><input type="checkbox"> One task </label> <br/>
</div>
<textarea id="message"> </textarea> <br/>
<input type="button" value="Add Task" id="add"></input>
```

JS

```
var a = document.getElementById('add') ;
a.addEventListener('click',say,false) ;

 function say() {
var b = document.getElementById('showTask') ;
var m = document.getElementById('message').value ;
var element = document.createElement('label') ;
var cbox = document.createElement('input');
cbox.setAttribute('type','checkbox') ;
element.appendChild(cbox) ;
element.innerHTML = m ;
b.appendChild(element) ;
var lbreak = document.createElement('br');
b.appendChild(lbreak) ;

}
```

In output only label's innerHTML  is showing ,there is no checkbox option display . i want to show checkbox before label text.

Comment: Can you try to put the `input checkbox` before the `<label>`?

Comment: Can you please check below code <div id="showTask">
<input type="checkbox" /> <label>One task </label> 
</div>
<br/>
<textarea id="message"> </textarea> <br/>
<input type="button" value="Add Task" id="add"/>

Comment: @C0dekid       i try than only checkbox showing not label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the contents of the label by using `innerHTML` instead append a text node like

```js
var a = document.getElementById('add');
a.addEventListener('click', say, false);

function say() {
  var b = document.getElementById('showTask');
  var m = document.getElementById('message').value;
  var element = document.createElement('label');
  var cbox = document.createElement('input');
  cbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  element.appendChild(cbox);
  element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(m))
  b.appendChild(element);
  var lbreak = document.createElement('br');
  b.appendChild(lbreak);

}
```

```html
<div id="showTask">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">One task</label>
  <br/>
</div>
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Add Task" id="add" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like the snippet below...
simple and easy to understand

```js
var a = document.getElementById('add') ;
a.addEventListener('click',say,false) ;

 function say() {
var b = document.getElementById('showTask') ;
var m = document.getElementById('message').value ;
var newInput="<label><input type='checkbox'>"+m+"</label><br/>";

var current_b=b.innerHTML+newInput;
b.innerHTML=current_b ;
}
```

```html
<div id="showTask">
<label><input type="checkbox"> One task </label> <br/>
</div>
<textarea id="message"> </textarea> <br/>
<input type="button" value="Add Task" id="add" />
```